# Negation without verb

Tags: negation

I read the following form in some source code comments:

> Someone requested we not relay stuff

Though it is usually not a source of inspiration for literary English, it got me wondering whether this was actually acceptable or just a short-hand to get the idea. Shouldn't it rather be something like

> Someone requested that we do not relay stuff

or

> Someone requested from us not to relay stuff

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence "Someone requested we not relay stuff" would be a perfectly proper (or at least better) usage of the subjunctive if "that" were not omitted:

> Someone requested **that** we not relay stuff.

**To request** is one of the verbs in English which can reveal the subjective mood. In English, the subjunctive has a present and a past form. The present form, which is used here, is the base form of the verb, or "bare infinitive," without the "to."

Comment: Just to be sure that I understand correctly, this is because the subjunctive does not require an auxiliary for the negation, not just something specific to **to request**?

Comment: @Anab - Precisely! The _not_ is all you need. "I require that he not speak." "I suggest that they not investigate." "I insist that you not stand."

Comment: Thank you, my knowledge of the subjunctive was limited to the irregular _were_ and I had never picked up on that one. :)